# Is there a way to renew IDP session token from a Client in Identity Server

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver3, openid-connect

I am using Identity Server to achieve Single Sign In/Out for the apps at my company. Is there any way to make it so that when a Client's cookie is renewed (via Sliding Expiration) it **also goes to the IDP and renews the expire time on the it's session cookie**? The goal is to be able to have a shared 1 hour sliding expiration across all apps even after the IDP sessions should have expired.

The only way I can think of achieving this right now is to create some middleware that examines the cookie on the Client and if it's close to expiring then add an iframe to call an endpoint on the IDP to tell it to renew it's cookie also. Am I on the right track? Is there a mechanism like this built into Identity Server and if so what is the endpoint?

**Edit for clarity:**

### The Problem

- Go to Client A @ 10:00

  - Redirect to IDP and log in
  - Redirect back to client

    - Now have a session on Client A and the IDP until 10:10
  - Stay active on Client A until 10:15 then go to Client B
  - **User has to log in again because the Client A site has kept it's cookie alive but IDP has expired** - *this is where I want Client A to call slide on the IDP to keep it's session active along with any Client to I can go to Client B without logging in again*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My situation is different than what `@Brock Allen`'s answer solves. Since we are using the authentication all internally I need to keep the **STS session cookie** alive while a user is browsing a site. This way if the STS cookie expires in an hour but a user is active on any Client site for >1 hour they can then go to another Client site and not have to log into the STS again.

I have solved the problem with the following code on the IDP:

```
public class Startup
{
    //...
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    { 
        //...
        app.Map("/identity", appBuilder =>
        {
            var idSrvOptions = new IdentityServerOptions
                { /* Your IdSrv config options here */ };

            appBuilder.UseIdentityServer(idSrvOptions);

            appBuilder.Map("/slide", identityAppBuilder =>
            {
                identityAppBuilder.Run(async context =>
                {
                    var cookie = context.Environment.ResolveDependency<SessionCookie>();
                    cookie.ClearSessionId();
                    cookie.IssueSessionId(null);
                    await Task.FromResult(0);
                });
            });
        });
   }
}
```

From the Client/Relying Parties I have the following JavaScript (which just puts a non-visible image in the body of the html and refreshes in src every X minutes if the user is active - which will slide the STS's cookie w/o having to worry about iframes). This could possibley be put in middleware to inject it automatically into all html responses that contain a `<body>` tag or simply added to a layout file:

```
 (function () {
    this.cookieDuration = 10000;
    this.lastAction = new Date();

    this.img = document.createElement('img');
    this.img.src = 'https://myStsDomain.com/identity/slide';
    this.img.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
    document.body.appendChild(img);

    setInterval(refreshStsCookie, cookieDuration * .5);

    document.addEventListener('click',
        function() {
            if (isLastActionLessThanCookieDuration()) {
                lastAction = new Date();
            }
        });

    function isLastActionLessThanCookieDuration() {
        return (new Date() - lastAction) < cookieDuration;
    }

    function refreshStsCookie() {
        if (isLastActionLessThanCookieDuration()) {
            img.src = img.src;
        }
    }
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can request a refresh token and then use that to obtain a new access token.

Comment: It is my understanding that a refresh token will allow for the Client to maintain access to APIs after the IDP session has expired.

I need the ability for the user to be able to go to another Client after the IDP session cookie expires (after the default 10 hours for example) and be logged in w/o typing credentials again. So when one Client's local session cookie is refreshed it also refreshes the session cookie on the IDP.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work that way. The user will have to login again.

Comment: @BrockAllen what then is the purpose of the SlidingExpiration field in the cookie options on IDSrv? How does one make this expiration "slide"?